# SQL/PHP query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for help with optimizing queries and understanding how to do it myself in the future.

I've got the DB exported for easy use - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwocqwuxl1bv3rt/DB_BF.zip?dl=0

The queries loading times can be seen on these pages -

http://89.163.173.82/DCS/blueflag/Pilots.php

http://89.163.173.82/DCS/blueflag/Events.php

http://89.163.173.82/DCS/blueflag/Player.php?term=Reaper6

So far I tried to do some optimizations by adding indexes and reducing the selected columns, but no big effect.
I'm not sure how to alter these big queries to do the same procedure but optimized.

First query-

```
SELECT DeadTbl.TIME AS 'Time',DeadTbl.Event AS 'Event',DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Target Coalition',DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Target Player',DeadTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Target Type',DeadTbl.InitiatorGroupCat
    ,HitTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Coalition',HitTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Player',HitTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Type',HitTbl.WeaponCat AS 'Weapon Category',HitTbl.WeaponName AS 'Weapon Name'
FROM (
    SELECT TIME,InitiatorID,EVENT,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorType,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorGroupCat
    FROM BlueFlagR2
    WHERE (EVENT = 'S_EVENT_DEAD'OR EVENT = 'S_EVENT_CRASH'OR EVENT = 'S_EVENT_PLAYER_LEAVE_UNIT')
        AND InitiatorGroupCat != ''
    ) AS DeadTbl
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`Time`) AS `Time`
        ,InitiatorID,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorType
        ,WeaponCat,WeaponName
        ,TargetID,TargetCoa,TargetType,TargetPlayer
    FROM BlueFlagR2
    WHERE EVENT = 'S_EVENT_HIT'
        AND InitiatorID != 0
        AND InitiatorPlayer != 'No Initiator'
    GROUP BY InitiatorID,InitiatorPlayer,TargetID,TargetType
) AS HitTbl ON DeadTbl.InitiatorID = HitTbl.TargetID
    AND DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa = HitTbl.TargetCoa
    AND DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer = HitTbl.TargetPlayer
    AND DeadTbl.InitiatorType = HitTbl.TargetType
    AND HitTbl.TIME <= DeadTbl.TIME
GROUP BY DeadTbl.InitiatorID,DeadTbl.TIME,HitTbl.InitiatorID
ORDER BY DeadTbl.TIME ASC
```

Second query:

```
SELECT K.Player AS Player, K.Ground AS Ground, K.Airplane AS Airplane, K.Helicopter AS Helicopter, K.Ship AS Ship, K.Total AS Total, IFNULL(D.Total,0) AS Deaths, (CASE WHEN D.Total IS NULL THEN K.Total ELSE K.Total/D.Total END) AS KD_Ratio
FROM 
(
SELECT PlayerTable.Player AS 'Player', SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'GROUND_UNIT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ground, SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'AIRPLANE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Airplane, SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'HELICOPTER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Helicopter, SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'SHIP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ship, COUNT(PlayerTable.`Target Player`) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT DeadTbl.Time AS 'Time', HitTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Coalition', HitTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Player', HitTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Type',HitTbl.WeaponCat AS 'Weapon Category',HitTbl.WeaponName AS 'Weapon Name', DeadTbl.Event AS 'Event', DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Target Coalition', DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Target Player', DeadTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Target Type', DeadTbl.InitiatorGroupCat
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT TIME,InitiatorID,EVENT,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorType,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorGroupCat
        FROM BlueFlagR2
        WHERE (EVENT = 'S_EVENT_DEAD' OR EVENT = 'S_EVENT_CRASH' OR EVENT='S_EVENT_PLAYER_LEAVE_UNIT')
        AND InitiatorGroupCat != ''
        ) AS DeadTbl
    JOIN
        (
        SELECT MAX(`Time`) AS `Time`,InitiatorID,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorType,WeaponCat,WeaponName,TargetID,TargetCoa,TargetType,TargetPlayer
        FROM BlueFlagR2
        WHERE EVENT = 'S_EVENT_HIT' AND InitiatorID!=0 AND InitiatorPlayer!='No Initiator'
        GROUP BY InitiatorID,InitiatorPlayer,TargetID,TargetType
        ) AS HitTbl
    ON DeadTbl.InitiatorID = HitTbl.TargetID AND DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa = HitTbl.TargetCoa AND DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer = HitTbl.TargetPlayer AND DeadTbl.InitiatorType = HitTbl.TargetType AND HitTbl.Time <= DeadTbl.Time
    GROUP BY DeadTbl.InitiatorID,DeadTbl.Time,HitTbl.InitiatorID
) AS PlayerTable
GROUP BY PlayerTable.Player
) AS K
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT InitiatorPlayer, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM BlueFlagR2
WHERE (EVENT = 'S_EVENT_DEAD' OR EVENT = 'S_EVENT_CRASH')
AND (InitiatorGroupCat = 'AIRPLANE' OR InitiatorGroupCat = 'HELICOPTER')
AND InitiatorPlayer != 'AI'
GROUP BY InitiatorPlayer
) AS D
ON K.Player = D.InitiatorPlayer
WHERE Player != 'AI' AND Player != '' AND Player != 'No Initiator'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN KD_Ratio = 'Infinite' THEN K.Total
ELSE KD_Ratio END DESC
```

They are basically similar as the core of it is the same.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Many of those subqueries are probably destroying any benefits indexing might give you. Try rewriting them without; as an example, in the first query those two tables can probably be JOINed directly and their separate WHEREs be merged.

Comment: A first step to checking any query that needs optimising should be to do an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) on that query, to see how the database is executing it, and what indexes are being used

Comment: Is this for Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?  You have tagged the question with both.

Comment: MySQL.Uueerdo can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You're also using an **or** where you may be able to use **in**

WHERE EVENT in ( 'S_EVENT_DEAD', 'S_EVENT_CRASH', 'S_EVENT_PLAYER_LEAVE_UNIT')

**Or** is very slow use it sparingly and always list the most likely outcome first in the arguments.

Comment: I will try that and report back

Answer (score 0):

Optimized First query-

```
    SELECT  * 
    INTO    #BlueFlagR2IGC
    FROM    BlueFlagR2

    DELETE FROM #BlueFlagR2IGC
    WHERE InitiatorGroupCat != ''


    SELECT  * 
    INTO    #BlueFlagR2IP
    FROM    BlueFlagR2

    DELETE FROM #BlueFlagR2IP
    WHERE InitiatorID = 0
    AND InitiatorPlayer = 'No Initiator'


    SELECT DeadTbl.TIME AS 'Time',DeadTbl.Event AS 'Event',DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Target Coalition',DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Target Player',DeadTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Target Type',DeadTbl.InitiatorGroupCat
        ,HitTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Coalition',HitTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Player',HitTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Type',HitTbl.WeaponCat AS 'Weapon Category',HitTbl.WeaponName AS 'Weapon Name'
    FROM (
        SELECT TIME,InitiatorID,EVENT,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorType,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorGroupCat
        FROM #BlueFlagR2IGC
        WHERE EVENT in ('S_EVENT_DEAD','S_EVENT_CRASH','S_EVENT_PLAYER_LEAVE_UNIT')

        ) AS DeadTbl
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(`Time`) AS `Time`
            ,InitiatorID,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorType
            ,WeaponCat,WeaponName
            ,TargetID,TargetCoa,TargetType,TargetPlayer
        FROM #BlueFlagR2IP
        WHERE EVENT = 'S_EVENT_HIT'
        GROUP BY InitiatorID,InitiatorPlayer,TargetID,TargetType
    ) AS HitTbl ON DeadTbl.InitiatorID = HitTbl.TargetID
        AND DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa = HitTbl.TargetCoa
        AND DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer = HitTbl.TargetPlayer
        AND DeadTbl.InitiatorType = HitTbl.TargetType
        AND HitTbl.TIME <= DeadTbl.TIME
    GROUP BY DeadTbl.InitiatorID,DeadTbl.TIME,HitTbl.InitiatorID
    ORDER BY DeadTbl.TIME ASC


    drop table #BlueFlagR2IGC
   drop table #BlueFlagR2IP
```

Optimized Second query:

```
SELECT  * 
INTO    #BlueFlagR2IGC
FROM    BlueFlagR2

DELETE FROM #BlueFlagR2IGC
WHERE InitiatorGroupCat != ''


SELECT  * 
INTO    #BlueFlagR2IP
FROM    BlueFlagR2

DELETE FROM #BlueFlagR2IP
WHERE InitiatorID = 0
AND InitiatorPlayer = 'No Initiator'


SELECT  * 
INTO    #BlueFlagR2AI
FROM    BlueFlagR2

DELETE FROM #BlueFlagR2AI
WHERE InitiatorPlayer = 'AI'


if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#target') is not null 
drop table #target

SELECT K.Player AS Player, K.Ground AS Ground, K.Airplane AS Airplane, K.Helicopter AS Helicopter, K.Ship AS Ship, K.Total AS Total, IFNULL(D.Total,0) AS Deaths, (CASE WHEN D.Total IS NULL THEN K.Total ELSE K.Total/D.Total END) AS KD_Ratio
INTO #target
FROM 
(
SELECT PlayerTable.Player AS 'Player', SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'GROUND_UNIT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ground, SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'AIRPLANE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Airplane, SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'HELICOPTER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Helicopter, SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerTable.InitiatorGroupCat = 'SHIP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ship, COUNT(PlayerTable.`Target Player`) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT DeadTbl.Time AS 'Time', HitTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Coalition', HitTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Player', HitTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Type',HitTbl.WeaponCat AS 'Weapon Category',HitTbl.WeaponName AS 'Weapon Name', DeadTbl.Event AS 'Event', DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa AS 'Target Coalition', DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer AS 'Target Player', DeadTbl.InitiatorType AS 'Target Type', DeadTbl.InitiatorGroupCat
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT TIME,InitiatorID,EVENT,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorType,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorGroupCat
        FROM #BlueFlagR2IGC
        WHERE EVENT in ('S_EVENT_DEAD','S_EVENT_CRASH','S_EVENT_PLAYER_LEAVE_UNIT')
        ) AS DeadTbl
    JOIN
        (
        SELECT MAX(`Time`) AS `Time`,InitiatorID,InitiatorCoa,InitiatorPlayer,InitiatorType,WeaponCat,WeaponName,TargetID,TargetCoa,TargetType,TargetPlayer
        FROM #BlueFlagR2IP
        WHERE EVENT = 'S_EVENT_HIT' 
        GROUP BY InitiatorID,InitiatorPlayer,TargetID,TargetType
        ) AS HitTbl
    ON DeadTbl.InitiatorID = HitTbl.TargetID AND DeadTbl.InitiatorCoa = HitTbl.TargetCoa AND DeadTbl.InitiatorPlayer = HitTbl.TargetPlayer AND DeadTbl.InitiatorType = HitTbl.TargetType AND HitTbl.Time <= DeadTbl.Time
    GROUP BY DeadTbl.InitiatorID,DeadTbl.Time,HitTbl.InitiatorID
) AS PlayerTable
GROUP BY PlayerTable.Player
) AS K



DELETE FROM #target
WHERE Player = 'AI' 
AND Player = '' 
AND Player = 'No Initiator'

SELECT  k.*
FROM    #target k
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT InitiatorPlayer, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM #BlueFlagR2AI
WHERE EVENT in ('S_EVENT_DEAD', 'S_EVENT_CRASH')
AND     InitiatorGroupCat in ( 'AIRPLANE', 'HELICOPTER')
GROUP BY InitiatorPlayer
) AS D
ON K.Player = D.InitiatorPlayer
ORDER BY CASE WHEN KD_Ratio = 'Infinite' THEN K.Total
ELSE KD_Ratio END DESC

drop table #BlueFlagR2IGC
drop table #BlueFlagR2IP
drop table #BlueFlagR2AI
```

i have updated for drop table for MY SQL. i am not sure how to do that in MY SQL. Just sure about that if we use not equal (!=) in query will take more time.

Comment: This is MySQL, I think that's why your methods are not working here?

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BlueFlagR2IGC') is not null 
drop table #BlueFlagR2IGC
' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue isn't in the sql itself, but in the way you created the database. you are using varchars to almost everything. That is not a good database-structure. You should create new tables for weapons, weaponscategory etc... and create relationsships to those tables. That's the whole point of using a relational database! :-)

Comment: Ok I get your point.
You mean create category tables with PKs which will indicate the relevant informatoin instead of storing all in 1 table.
I'll have a go at starting to do that.

Comment: @Morrtz - yes exactly. One other thing is that would "optimize" it further is not actually create an sql for the WHOLE database, but just limit it to 10 rows (if you are using pagination load next page with ajax)